# Mocking a method via jest.spyOn is failing

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am trying unsuccessfully to mock a Promise:

utils.js

```
export const fetching = () => {
  const data = [1,2,3];
  return new Promise(resolve=>resolve(data));
}
```

MyComponent

```
export function MyComponent() {
  ...
  useEffect(()=>{
    async function callback() {
      const fetchedData = await fetching();
    }
    callback();
  }, []);

  return (
    ...
  );
}
```

MyTest

```
import * as myStuff from ...;
jest.spyOn(myStuff, 'fetching').mockImplementation(()=>Promise.resolve([5]))


test('should ...', async () => {
  // given 
  render(<MyComponent/>);
  
});
```

What am I getting as `fetchedData` by running the above test is `undefined` instead of `[5]`. Any idea why?

Comment: Hmmm... seems like I'm facing the same thing in nextjs12. Did you happen to figure this out? @unknown-developer?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the call in `useEffect` which means it's triggering after the component is actually mounted. Your test is async, but you're not advancing timers. Try:

```js
jest.useFakeTimers()

const fetchSpy = jest.spyOn(myStuff, 'fetching').mockImplementation(()=>Promise.resolve([5]))

test('should ...', async () => {
  // given 
  render(<MyComponent/>);

 // here, we essentially push time forward, after useEffect has been triggered by the mounted component
  act(() => { 
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000)
  })

  expect(fetchSpy).toBeCalled()
});
```